# How to project 3D point into camera under the influence of focal length and use Python?

Tags: python, 3d-view, camera

The manual introduces the world_to_camera_View maps 3D to 2D, but ignores the influence of focal length parameters. Is there a method with focal length parameters in blender API? Is it possible to implement it in Python? thank you!

thank you!

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

from mathutils import Vector
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

scene = bpy.context.scene

cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
vec = Vector()
vec.x, vec.y, vec.z = 0, 0, 0

cam.data.lens = 50 # 50mm
xy = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, vec)
print(xy)

cam.data.lens = 100
xy = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, vec)
print(xy)
```